# Why do vectors declared without size need push_back to accept inputs with cin?

Tags: c++

Why is it that a vector with declared size can accept input directly from `cin` like so:

```
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> a(n);//Vector declared with size
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
```

But a vector declared without a size needs a `push_back()` function to accept inputs like:

```
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> a;//Vector declared WITHOUT size
int input;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>input;
    a.push_back(input);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the `[]` operator on a vector assumes that the object at the given index is valid. If your `vector` hasn't allocated its internal buffer to fit this index, this is undefined behavior. Alternatively, the `push_back()` simply appends onto the end of the `vector` and reallocates a larger internal buffer if one is needed, so it never performs undefined behavior in the same way. By explicitly resizing your vector prior to accessing it with `[]`, the array is resized such that accessing elements `0` to `n-1` is defined, but anything beyond `n-1` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Its because

```
vector<int> a(n);
```

pre-allocates your vector with `n` elements as mentioned [here (see constructor variant (2) please)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), while

```
vector<int> a;
```

doesn't, and you have to add the elements one by one.

---

If you use the `operator[]` with a `std::vector`, it needs to be assured, that an element exists at the used index, i.e. the index should be less than `std::vector<T>::size()`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example code your using vector constructor reserving place for n-elements, and you can use random access operator. Random access operator is not checking size of memory.

In second code you're creating empty vector. `push_back` is needed for additional step of memory allocation for an `int` object.

cpp reference with constructor functions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector look in (3)

Answer (score 1):

reason is quite simple: when you declare a size (let's say k) you allocate k elements. behind the scene there's a T* vec = new T[k]; call of some sort once you do each of the k elements exist and not only that but with default value.

when we do something like std::vector v;
it's size is 0, nothing was allocated thus we need to create the spots either via push_back or emplace_back (which is better since you don't use copy constructor but build it directly) when you say v[0] prior to any action you're accessing address that doesn't exist  while in the previous scerino it does

Answer (score 1):

Because first vector, have preallocated memory and then you can refer to particular element by operator[].

If you would use operator on the second vector before pushing some elements, the behavior would be undefined.

Comment: No, vectors do not throw exceptions on `op[]`.